# GMOD Lua Use type doesn't matter?

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

recently I have been creating an imitation HarborRP gamemode for Garry's Mod, and I'm trying to recreate the Smuggler NPC (You'll know what I mean if you've ever played HarborRP) So basically I want the NPC to open ONE Derma-Frame window when the player presses their use key on it. I have the NPC created and all of that, but when the player simply presses their use key on the NPC, a million windows pop up, I have the NPC/Entity's use type set to SIMPLE_USE, but it seems like that doesn't matter because so many windows pop up. the VGUI/Derma Frame's settings is set to MakePopup() but that doesn't matter either. See if you can find whats wrong with it, I have very little knowledge of LUA.

init.lua file:

```
include("shared.lua")
AddCSLuaFile("cl_init.lua")
AddCSLuaFile("shared.lua")

util.AddNetworkString("smug")
hook.Add("PlayerUse", "menuu", function(ply, ent)

    net.Start("smug")
    net.Send(ply)

end)

function ENT:Initialize()
    self:SetModel('models/humans/group01/female_01.mdl')
    self:SetHullType(HULL_HUMAN)
    self:SetHullSizeNormal()
    self:SetNPCState(NPC_STATE_SCRIPT)
    self:SetSolid(SOLID_BBOX)
    self:SetUseType(SIMPLE_USE)
    self:DropToFloor()
end
```

cl_init.lua file:

```
include("shared.lua")

function ENT:Draw()
    self.Entity:DrawModel()
end

net.Receive("smug", function()
if( !frame ) then
    local frame = vgui.Create("DFrame")

    frame:SetSize(900,600)
    frame:SetPos(ScrW()/2-450,ScrH()/2-300)
    frame:SetVisible(true)
    frame:MakePopup()

    frame:SetDeleteOnClose(true)
    elseif (frame) then print("HI")
end
end)
```

shared.lua file:

```
ENT.Base = "base_ai"
ENT.Type = "ai"
ENT.PrintName = "[DEV] Smuggler NPC"
ENT.Category = "InVaLiD's HBRP Entities"
ENT.Author = "InVaLiD"
ENT.Spawnable = true
ENT.AdminSpawnable = true
ENT.AutomaticFrameAdvance = true
```

Something To Note

1. All of these files are in the addons/smug_npc/lua/entities/ folder.
2. Yes, I know I have weird names for things, that's just me.
3. I have a basic to no knowledge of lua, so explain things please :)
4. I really do appreciate your help, and your will to help people, please know that I thank you all for being here just to sort other people's problems even though you could be spending your time doing something productive, Thank you!

Comment: The other things that are weird are weird probably because this is for a game named "Garry's Mod" and it derives from the "DarkRP" gamemode in said game. to address the other issue about me making a gamemode with little-to-zero knowledge of lua, there really aren't any "beginner" tutorials on GMOD Lua, all the other tutorials just kinda chuck you in and say "This is how you do it, now do it.". another reason why I'm creating a GMOD gamemode as a starting point is because I wan't to cross it off of my bucket list. Now to address "!frame", !frame does not seem to output an error in the console.

Comment: So idk, It doesn't seem to output an error, just calls the network over and over, resulting in a lot of windows popping up.

Comment: @Piglet GMod lua syntax differs slightly from normal adding C# like syntax E.g. // comments, ! negation and the use of && and ||.

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code that does net.Send into the entities ENT:Use function rather than on the PlayerUse hook.

```
function ENT:Use(ply)
    net.Start("smug")
    net.Send(ply)
end
```

The below line which you already have in your code in the initialize function makes the entity call the ENT:Use function once when a player presses E on it, which it seems that you want to do so that is good:

```
self:SetUseType(SIMPLE_USE)
```

Also, I recommend checking out the gmod forums if you need developer help in future.

GMod forums: https://gmod.facepunch.com/f

Comment: Okay, so now when I press "E", nothing happens. here is where I placed everything:

Comment: init.lua:
include("shared.lua")
AddCSLuaFile("cl_init.lua")
AddCSLuaFile("shared.lua")

util.AddNetworkString("smug")
function ENT:Initialize()
 self:SetModel('models/humans/group01/female_01.mdl')
 self:SetHullType(HULL_HUMAN)
 self:SetHullSizeNormal()
 self:SetNPCState(NPC_STATE_SCRIPT)
 self:SetSolid(SOLID_BBOX)
 self:SetUseType(SIMPLE_USE)
 self:DropToFloor()
end
 
function ENT:Use(ply)
    net.Start("smug")
    net.Send(ply)
end

Comment: hm :\ it seems like no matter the placement of the function, not even my print displays.                                                                                              
' util.AddNetworkString("smug")
function ENT:Use(ply)
 print("Ow! Stop using me")
    net.Start("smug")
    net.Send(ply)
end
 '

Comment: Can you update your original question containing all the relevant code in code blocks? It's very difficult to read in comments.